# is it possible to declare an user group for the remote user in aliases.drushrc.php

Tags: drush

I have a different user group for apache on my remote server clould i specify a group for drush sync like remote-user user adds the user or in some similar way
?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; in unix, the group ownership is attached to the user.  Use `usermod -a -G` to add the desired group permanently to your remote user.  See [man usermod](http://linux.die.net/man/8/usermod) for more information.